# Is there a mathematics term for the equivalent of "stanza"?

Tags: terminology

Is there a mathematics term for the equivalent of "stanza"?  By this I mean a repeated unit of similar properties, but not exactly the same.  For example
$$ f(x)=(1-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4})+(\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{8})+(\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{10}-\frac{1}{12})+...  $$
Here the brackets are deliberately put in so show the "stanza", even though they aren't necessary the same expression.

Comment: I would just call those the terms.

Comment: I don't know of a term, but you could highlight the similarity with something like: $g(x)=\frac1{2x-1}-\frac1{4x-2}-\frac1{4x}$ giving $f(x)=g(1)+g(2)+g(3)+\dots$. BTW, $f(x)$ doesn't seem to depend on $x$.